# Pre-installation request for 11gR2 RAC Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

before 11gR2 RAC installation, does the port needs to be open between the 2 nodes which will be RACed? also does it need to be able to ping each other between the nodes for scan name? os is linux x86_64 redhat. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read the 2-day real application clusters guide from oracle. Basically you need the following for each node:

- public ip
- virtual ip (which has to be on the same subnet as the public one)
- private ip

In addition you also need 3 scan addresses.

The scan addresses and virtual-ip **must** not be pingable before you start the clusterware installation. The public and the private must be pingable.